# Find whether all checkbox are checked within a parent div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I am trying to get the state of two input checkboxes within a div element. I need to set a flag variable to true only if both the checkboxes are checked. If any of the input checkbox is unchecked , then it should be set to false.

I tried this using for loop using the below code

```
var oParNode = oNode.ParentNode;
if (null != oParNode) {

  for (var i = 0; i < oNode.ParentNode.Nodes.length; i++) {
    if (oNode.ParentNode.Nodes[i].Checked) {
      checked = true;
    }
    else {
      checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

In this code , Nodes[i] returns the input element. When I check the first checkbox first and the second one next this loop works fine but when I check the second one first , the checked variable is set to true based on the second checkbox value which is executed at last.

**Expected:** I need to return "checked" to be true only if both checkboxes are checked .

Can some one suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break your loop in case any of checkbox is not checked

```
 var oParNode = oNode.ParentNode;
 if (null != oParNode) {
 for (var i = 0; i < oNode.ParentNode.Nodes.length; i++) {
   if (oNode.ParentNode.Nodes[i].Checked) {
     checked = true;
   }  else {
      checked = false;
      break;
   }
 }
}
```

You can simply [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method of array instead of loop

```
let checkedAll = oNode.ParentNode.Nodes.every(element => element.checked )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), to check if there's an unchecked one:

```
var checked = oNode.ParentNode.Nodes.some(check => !check.checked)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems for second node it is overriding the value. If you know there are two checkboxes you can directly check it like this.

```
if (oNode.ParentNode.Nodes[0].Checked && oNode.ParentNode.Nodes[1].Checked) {
    checked = true;
} else {
   checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, if it is only 2 I can use this but clients may use a different set of data which may have multiple checkboxes within a parent element. In such case is there any generic way to do this.?

Comment: you can break the loop in that case as Code Maniac suggested in other answer. @keerthana

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding all checked, find unchecked instead since this is what you are looking for.

```
var checked = true;
for (var i = 0; i < oNode.ParentNode.Nodes.length; i++) {
    if (!oNode.ParentNode.Nodes[i].Checked) {
       checked = false;
       break;
    }
}
```